# Why are these two upper bounds the same?

Tags: integration, estimation, upper-lower-bounds

I'm trying to upper bound the quantity $\int_t^{\infty} e^{-x^2} dx$ as a function of $t$. I came up with two ways of doing this:

1. We have that $(x-t)^2 = x^2 -2tx + t^2 \ge 0 \implies -x^2 \le -2tx + t^2$, so that $\int_t^{\infty} e^{-x^2} dx \le \int_t^{\infty} e^{-2tx}e^{t^2} dx= e^{t^2} \int_t^{\infty} e^{-2tx} dx = e^{t^2} \left(-\frac{1}{2t} e^{-2tx}\bigg\rvert_{x=t}^{x=\infty}\right) = \frac{1}{2t}e^{-t^2}$.
2. We have, on the domain $x \in [t, \infty)$, that $x \ge t \implies 1 \le \frac{x}{t}$, so that
   $\int_t^{\infty}e^{-x^2} dx \le \int_t^{\infty} \frac{x}{t} e^{-x^2} dx = \frac{1}{t} \left(-\frac{1}{2}e^{-x^2} \bigg \rvert_{x=t}^{x=\infty}\right) = \frac{1}{2t} e^{-t^2}$.

Is it a coincidence that these two totally different methods give the same upper bounds? Or is there a connection between these two estimates that I'm not realizing?

Comment: The weird thing is that the first method does not use the fact $x \geq t$...

Comment: The first estimate would be unbounded on the left hand side, so it wouldn't be so useful outside $[t, \infty)$... Maybe that answers your thought?

Comment: What happens if you use $(x-\frac{t}{2})^2 \geq 0$ ?

Comment: Interesting idea... when you use $(x-a)^2 \ge 0$ you obtain an upper bound of $\frac{1}{2a}e^{t^2 -2at}$, which is minimized when $2a^2-2at-1 = 0 \implies a = \frac{t}{2} + \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{t^2+2}$, not $a = t$ - so my first bound can actually be improved!

Comment: The given integral is 

$$\int_t^{\infty} e^{-x^2} \,dx, $$

with the domain $x\in[t,\infty)$ so $x\ge t$ by definition. Therefore

\begin{align}x\ge t &\iff (x-t)\ge 0\\ 
&\implies(x-t)^2 \ge 0\\
&\iff x^2 -2tx + t^2 \ge 0 \\
&\iff-x^2 \le -2tx + t^2.
\end{align}

So, the two inequalities are related. They lead to same bound since $x\ge t \implies -x^2 \le -2tx + t^2$.

Comment: @Axion004 Similarly we can obtain $x\le t\Leftrightarrow  (t-x)\ge 0 \Rightarrow  \dots (t-x)^2\ge 0\dots$.

Answer (score 2):

The coincedence is that from the point of view of an integral your estimations are the same. Why?

Let's recall the substitution rule for integrals:
For $\varphi \in C^1([a,b])$ it holds
$$\int_{a}^{b} f(\varphi(x)) \cdot \varphi'(x)\,\mathrm{d}x = \int_{\varphi(a)}^{\varphi(b)} f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$$

If we now have a closer look we can see that both of your estimations are of the form of the LHS:

For $$f(x) = \frac{1}{2}\exp(-tx)$$ and $$\varphi_1(x) = 2x-t$$ we get $$\int_{t}^{\infty} f(\varphi_1(x)) \cdot \varphi_1'(x)\,\mathrm{d}x = \int_t^\infty \exp(-2tx+t^2) \,\mathrm{d}x$$ for your first estimator while taking

$$\varphi_2(x) = \frac{x^2}{t}$$ it gives us $$\int_{t}^{\infty} f(\varphi_2(x)) \cdot \varphi_2'(x)\,\mathrm{d}x = \int_t^\infty \frac{x}{t}\exp(-x^2) \,\mathrm{d}x$$ so your second estimator.
And because it holds $$\varphi_1(t) = \varphi_2(t) = t$$ as well as $$\varphi_1(\infty) = \varphi_2(\infty) = \infty$$ both functions give the same result by using the substitution rule namely $$\int_{\varphi(a)}^{\varphi(b)} f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x = \int_t^\infty \frac{1}{2}\exp(-tx) \,\mathrm{d}x$$

Moreover: Any suitable $\varphi \in C^1([t,\infty))$ with $\varphi(t) = t$ and $\varphi(\infty) = \infty$ will lead to the same result.

So what you did in both cases was actually estimating $\exp(-x^2)$ by $f(\varphi(x)) \cdot \varphi'(x)$ for a suitable $\varphi$

Answer (score -1):

You could also try and use the gaussian integral and taylor series to get that:
$$\int_t^\infty e^{-x^2}dx=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}+\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n+1}t^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)n!}$$
or if you take the first few terms you get:
$$I\approx\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}+\frac{t^3}{3}-t+O(-t^5)$$